# Itunes Connect - "Submit for Review" doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm attempting to submit my app for review with `Itunes Connect`. I've filled out everything necessary (I believe - it doesn't say I left anything blank). When I click "**Submit for Review**" it begins a cycle animation as if it working on something but shortly after it just stops. Does this mean my app was submitted? Is there any indication that would let me know? Thanks.

**Additional info**: Built with with the latest version of `RoboVM/Xcode`

Comment: Check that status of your app now. If it was submitted, it will say so.

Comment: Try submit accessing with Safari.

Comment: How do I check? It still says "Prepare for submission" and "submit for review" so I'll assume it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If still in "**Prepare for Submission**" then hasn't been submitted yet. Only changes to the status of Apple when changes to "**Waiting Review**".

You also can view the entire **stack of submission** in `Itunes Connect App` (Sample with complete process of submission).

[image: Sample]

Try submit with `Safari`, the `Itunes Connect` works better with this browser.

If you still can't submit your app **contact Apple** in https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php

Comment: Thanks. I've tried firefox and safari. I'll try chrome and contact them if that doesn't help.